# jQuery function to not inherit from parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a lot of nested divs inside eachother:

```
<div id="container_anatomy">
        <div id = "container_anatomy_painted">
             <div id="example"> Item1</div>
             <div id="example"> Item2</div>
             <div id="example"> Item3</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

I only want to make the outer div `"anatomy_part"` and `"container_anatomy_painted"` Draggable with this function:

```
var clicked = false,
  clickX;
$('#container_anatomy_painted').on({
  'mousemove': function(e) {
    clicked && updateScrollPos(e);
  },
  'mousedown': function(e) {
    clicked = true;
    clickX = e.pageX;
    clickY = e.pageY;

    last_x = $('#container_wrapper_anatomy').scrollLeft();
    last_y = $('#container_wrapper_anatomy').scrollTop();
    event.preventDefault();
  },
});
```

But right now even the "example"-items are movable. Is there a way to not make the nested divs inherit the same jquery function? So i can only `"mousemove"` on the `"container_anatomy_painted"`.

Comment: Using this function will give you nightmares in future. Go with libraries like jQuery UI: https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: "anatomy_part"? is that meant to reference something?  You also have a number of undefined variables there.

Comment: Multiple `id="example"` makes this markup invalid and will produce unexpected results. https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2 and https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H93.html

Answer (score 0):

You could bind to the child divs and within that bind use `event.stopPropagation();`